# VB.NET web service client accessing Java web service - connection aborted

Tags: java, vb.net, web-services, interop, cxf

I had a problem getting a VB.NET web service client to receive the response object from a Java web service.  In the process of posting this question someone from another department volunteered some code written for a similar situation.  I couldn't find this anywhere on the net so I'm completing my question to help others out.

```
Dim myService As New theService.TheService()
Dim objCurrentPrice As New myService.CurrentPrice

myService.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("webuser", "123pass")

objCurrentPrice = myService.getCurrentPrice("10211012343")
MessageBox.Show(objCurrentPrice.Description)
```

This failed at:

```
objCurrentPrice = myService.getCurrentPrice("10211012343")
```

With the inner exception stating the connection was aborted by the remote host.

Here is the code with the additional line that my co-worker gave:

```
Dim myService As New theService.TheService()
Dim objCurrentPrice As New myService.CurrentPrice

myService.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("webuser", "123pass")
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

objCurrentPrice = myService.getCurrentPrice("10211012343")
MessageBox.Show(objCurrentPrice.Description)
```

Which fixed the interoperability problem.  The web service is Apache CXF with some Spring elements mixed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this static variable like this:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
```